# Sort by Date and group parent / child documents

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a database with some documents in it. Some Documents have child documents associated with them. Every document has a column "createdat". If the document has no children, the column "iParentDoc" is 0. Otherwise the Number is equal to the column docID of the parent item.

Basically I want to sort primarily by the date of the Parentdoc and the children should be sorted by their date and shown directly after the parent, e.g.

```
Parent Doc0 (id: 1, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2015)
Parent Doc1 (id: 2, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2014)
- Child doc1 (id: 3, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-02-2014)
- Child doc2 (id: 4, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-03-2014)
```

The sorting especially gives issues when I change DESC / ASC sorting as per "createdat" column, as I get the result:

```
- Child doc2 (id: 4, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-03-2014)
- Child doc1 (id: 3, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-02-2014)
Parent Doc1 (id: 2, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2014)
Parent Doc0 (id: 1, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2015)
```

So sorting (according to createdat DESC / ASC) shall always be made by the Parentcolums and the children then coming afterwards. So it should be:

```
Parent Doc1 (id: 2, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2014)
- Child doc1 (id: 3, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-02-2014) 
- Child doc2 (id: 4, iParentDoc: 2, createdat: 01-03-2014)
Parent Doc0 (id: 1, iParentDoc: 0, createdat: 01-01-2015)
```

I tried this query, but it gives me odds, especially when sorting is reversed.

```
ORDER BY COALESCE( NULLIF(iParentDoc,0), id) DESC, NULLIF(iParentDoc,0) IS NOT NULL , createdat desc LIMIT 20
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
You can add another column parent_createdat, and insert the parent's document datetime when you set the parent id in iParentDoc.

then:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(parent_createdat,0), NULLIF(createdat,0)) DESC, createdat ASC
```